# go-mssqldb returns incorrect Id value

Tags: sql-server, go, uuid, guid

I'm using github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb package to access my MS SQL database.
However, when I'm trying to read Id value (uniqueidentifier) from the database, it returns another Id, than recorder in database. In my DB, I have 2 records, with id: 395322A6-88BA-164B-A3C6-36EB455B8999 and 1735B618-E5FB-448C-9446-7A5469A6C34D, but when database returns id 395322A6-88BA-164B-A3C6-36EB455B8999, I see it in go as a6225339-ba88-4b16-a3c6-36eb455b8999.
Currently, to parse Id I'm using

```
parsedUUID := uuid.New()
err := row.Scan(&parsedUUID, &dbLogin.Login)
```

I've also tried to read from Scan to string or byte array, but after `Sprintf("%x", arr)` I'm still getting the wrong Id

P.S. SQL, which I use:

```
SELECT Id, Log from dbo.Logs WHERE Log=@LOG
```

My code:
SQL:

```
create table Logs
(
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key,
    Log nvarchar(max),
    MetadataHash nvarchar(256)
)
```

Go:

```
cnUrl:= &url.URL{
        Scheme: driverName,
        Host:   host,
        User:   url.UserPassword(user, password),
    }
connString := cnUrl.String()
dbConnector, err := mssql.NewConnector(connString)
dbConnector.SessionInitSQL = "USE ELDB"
databaseConnection = sql.OpenDB(dbConnector)
row := databaseConnection.QueryRow("SELECT Id, Log from dbo.Logs WHERE Log=@LOG",
        sql.Named("LOG", log))
parsedUUID := uuid.New()
err := row.Scan(&parsedUUID, &dbLogin.Login)
```

And after calling `parsedUUID.String()`, I'm getting the wrong Id

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? That includes SQL to create the table and Go code. This may well be a bug in the driver package, but could just as well be one in your code.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Looks like it has the same bytes but in the wrong order.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sure, thank you for the advice! I've added my example